# Type of NSLayoutAnchor

Tags: swift, nslayoutanchor

No matter what I try I can't get the variations of this to work... What am I not getting?

```
func anchorType(for string:String) -> NSLayoutAnchor<AnyObject> {

    switch string {
    case "x":
        return NSLayoutXAxisAnchor
    case "y":
        return NSLayoutYAxisAnchor
    default:
        return NSLayoutDimension
    }
}
```

There seems to be no way to determine the class of an anchor.. :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is exactly what you're looking for but I think something like this should work:

```
func anchorType(for string:String) -> AnyClass {

    switch string {
    case "x":
        return NSLayoutXAxisAnchor.self
    case "y":
        return NSLayoutYAxisAnchor.self
    default:
        return NSLayoutDimension.self
    }
}
```

I'm not too familiar with this area but I would think that the reason you can't return NSLayoutAnchor is because that class is a generic class while it's subclasses are not.

Comment: Yeah, it wouldn't help because I'd still need to find out above what the class is

Comment: What do you mean "what the class is"? What are you trying to return?